# Integral Question using the Rule of Subsitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm confused as to why $ \int e^{kx}dx$ = $\frac{e^{kx}}{k} + C$. I'm using the rule of substitution and came to the conclusion that it should be $e^{kx}k$ because the derivative of $kx$ is $k$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to *divide* by the derivative of $kx$.

Comment: OK. The derivative of kx is k. Then the derivative of $e^{kx}k$ is $k^2\cdot e^{kx}$. This is not correct. The equation is: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(  a\cdot e^{kx}+C \right)=e^{kx}$$ calculate the factor a.

Comment: I'm still confused where the $ \frac {1}{k}$ comes from. Why do you have to divide by the derivative of $kx$.

Comment: @JacksonH The derivative of the antiderivative is the function itself. That is the equation, which I have posted. Just solve the equation for a.

Comment: Doesn't the rule state that you just multiply the derivative of $g(x)$ by $f(g(x)$. In this case the derivative of $g(x)$ would be the derivative of $kx$, which would be $k$ and that would be multiplied by $f(g(x))$ which in this case would be $e^{kx}$ so in total that would be $k*e^{kx}$.

Comment: @JacksonH No. The equation becomes $$a\cdot g'(x)\cdot e^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)}\Rightarrow a\cdot k \cdot e^{kx}=e^{kx} \Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{k}$$ $g'(x)$ has to be neutralized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\int e^{kx}dx$ means that you need to find a lot of function which $(\ f + C \ )'= e^{kx}$. As you said $(e^{kx})'=k\cdot e^{kx} \Rightarrow (\frac{e^{kx}}{k} + C)'= e^{kx} \Rightarrow f=\frac{e^{kx}}{k}$

Therefore $\int e^{kx}dx=\frac{e^{kx}}{k}+C$, where C set of all constants.

Answer (score 2):

For integrate $e^{kx}$ substitute $u=kx$ and $du=kdx$

$\frac{1}{k} \int e^{u}du$

The integral of $e^u$ is $e^{u}$

$=\frac{e^u}{k}+constant$

Substitute back for $u=kx$:

$=\frac{e^{kx}}{k}+c$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int e^{kx}\,dx\quad\text{let }u=kx\implies du=k\,dx\implies dx=\frac1k\,du\\
\int \frac1k e^u\,du=\frac1k\int e^u\,du=\frac1k e^u+C=\frac1k e^{kx}+C.$$